# Buckling reference using the FEM

Tags: finite-element, reference-request, solid-mechanics

I want to analyze buckling in a composite using the FEM. So far I have studied this references

- Zdenek P Bazant, Luigi Cedolin. Stability of Structures: Elastic, Inelastic, Fracture and Damage Theories. World Scientific Publishing Company, 2010.
- Wsben Byskov. Elementary Continuum Mechanics for Everyone.  Springer, 2013.

**Question:** Is there a better reference that tackle the problem of buckling from a numerical point of view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at this site:

http://shellbuckling.com/index.php

Dave Bushnell has pretty much written the book on computational techniques
for buckling analysis. There is a wealth of information on both classical and
computational approaches to buckling analysis here.

I would start with his survey paper:

http://shellbuckling.com/papers/bosor4/1981.pitfalls.pdf

It has remarkable insights into what buckling means both physically
and numerically.

His software, which you can download from this site, is based on finite difference
methods but the concepts are equally applicable to finite elements.